# How to get all variables declared in a method scope

Tags: c#, variables, methods, reflection, parameters

Is there any way to get all variables declared in a method and parameters received?

I am trying to get all the variables and its values in a method which I want to add to logs.
I could get the parameters received in the method defnition using  `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()`.
That too has one drawback I noticed that, I have to explicitly pass something specific to the method in order to take the value of the parameter.

What I want is, I want all the variables and its values declared in a method scope in a general way, without explicitly giving any method specific parameters(since I want to add the same logic to several method).
Any one please have your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as a side note, I wouldn't recommend doing that for logging. Logging millions of things you don't need will actually cause problems when trying to find useful stuff.
For example, imagine you have `var index = 0` and then a `while` loop inside your method and how that is going to add a lot of useless information to your logs.

Comment: If you look at the IL generated for a method, you'll see that the names of local variables are not always preserved.

Comment: "add the same logic to several method"? can you provide an example code of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is impossible. First, if you want to log **all** the values a variable receives in a method, consider the following code:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  int n = 0;
  for (;;)
    n++;
}
```

you'll have to create an infinitely long log, which is impossible.

Second, if you want to just know the **initial** value of a variable **without giving values to parameters**, consider the following:

```
void SomeMethod(int m)
{
  int n = m == 0 ? 1 : 2;
  ...
}
```

without knowing the value of `m`, you simply cannot know the value of `n`.

Third, even if you have all the parameter values, and you just want to know the initial value of a variable, it is still impossible, **in a general way**. In fact, you cannot even know whether a variable will get declared. Consider the following:

```
void SomeMethod(...some parameters...)
{
  ...some complex code...
      int n = 0;  // deep inside some complex control statements
  ...more complex code...
}
```

You cannot, **in general**, know whether that `int n = 0;` would get executed, so you cannot know whether variable `n` would be declared. This is one form of [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am asking for any c# method similar to MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()

Comment: @NCA, so ycsun answer suggests that no such methods :-)

Comment: @NCA, If you want to go inside the body of a method, reflection won't help you much. I don't think it is a good idea, but if you really want to go there, no matter what, perhaps you'd like to take a look at the [unmanaged APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ch59zxfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?